# How can I keep values without aggregation when resampling in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have minute financial data and want to resample for the day
however I want to retain the open for the first observation of the day and the close from the last observation of the day.

```
  DDate/Time       |  Symbol|    Open   |High   |Low    Close|  Volume 

2011-01-03 07:07:00|    BTP#| **58.92** |58.94  |58.70  |58.70  |26

2011-01-03 07:08:00|    BTP#|   58.82   |58.96| 58.82   |58.96| 25

.............

2011-02-28 16:49:00|    BTP#|   58.25   |58.25| 58.25   |58.25  |5

2011-02-28 17:03:00|    BTP#|   58.22   |58.22  |58.22| **58.22**|  1
```

I have manage to extract the values using the following groupby code 
but it creates havok with my index's and I will want to merge with other dataframes at a later date.

```py
test = btp.groupby(btp.index.date).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[[0, -1]])
```

Would be very grateful if someone has a beautiful solution

Comment: post expected result

Answer (score 0):

```
    btp = btp.resample('d').apply({'Open':'first', 'High':'max', 'Low':'min', 'Close':'last'})
```